AceEditor with rclipboard does not work inside modal
I have an aceEditor with a rclipboard button. This app works fine, I mean, the code inside the aceEditor is copied into the clipboard when I click the button:
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
library(rclipboard)

ui<-basicPage(
  rclipboardSetup()
  ,aceEditor(
    outputId = "aceEdId",
    mode="java",
    theme="cobalt",
    readOnly = F,
    height = "300px",
    tabSize = 1,
    value = "some code"
  )
  ,uiOutput("clip")
)    

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$clip <- renderUI({
    rclipButton(
      inputId = "clipbtn",
      label = "rclipButton Copy",
      clipText = input[["aceEdId"]],
      icon = icon("clipboard"),
      tooltip = "Click me... I dare you!",
      placement = "top",
      options = list(delay = list(show = 800, hide = 100), trigger = "hover")
    )
  })    
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)

Now, I have a datatable (with only one record) in which every row has a button. Those buttons opens a modal which contains another datatable (with only one row). When I click any row of this datatable an aceEditor with the button to copy to clipboard are displayed.
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
library(rclipboard)

shinyInput <- function(FUN, n, id, ...) {
  vapply(seq_len(n), function(i){
    as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
  }, character(1))
}

ui<-fluidPage(
  DTOutput('tbl1')
  ,rclipboardSetup()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$tbl1=renderDT({
    a=data.frame("col"=c(1))  
    a$btb=shinyInput(
      FUN = actionButton,
      n = nrow(a),
      id = 'btb_',
      label = "Button",
      onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue(\"btn_Modal\", this.id, {priority: \"event\"})',
    ) 
    a
  },selection = 'single',escape = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_Modal, {
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rclipboardSetup()
      ,DTOutput('tbl2')
      ,uiOutput('uiOut')
    ))
    
  })    

  observeEvent(input$tbl2_cell_clicked,{
    req(!is.na(input$tbl2_cell_clicked))
    
    output[["uiOut"]]<-renderUI({
      basicPage(
      rclipboardSetup()
      ,aceEditor(
        outputId = "aceEdId",
        value = "some code"
      )
      ,uiOutput("clip") 
      )
    })
    
  })  
  
  output$tbl2=renderDT({
    a=data.frame("col"=c(1))  
    a
  },selection = 'single')  
  
  output$clip <- renderUI({
    rclipButton(
      inputId = "clipbtn",
      label = "rclipButton Copy",
      clipText = input[["aceEdId"]]
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)


but in this case, the button to copy into the clipboard does not work. It does not show any error, just copy nothing. Any suggestions?

I'm not familiar with this package and I won't be very helpful. That said, here are two remarks: 1) Your app is too complex, you should first try without the DT tables; 2) Always look at the doc: there is an option modal = TRUE in case of usage in a modal.

It works. But I didn't try with the DT tables.
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
library(rclipboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rclipboardSetup(),
  actionButton("openModal", "Show modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Add clipboard buttons
  output$clip <- renderUI({
    rclipButton(
      inputId = "clipbtn", 
      label = "rclipButton Copy", 
      clipText = input$aceEdId, 
      icon = icon("clipboard"),
      tooltip = "Click me to copy the content of the text field to the clipboard!",
      options = list(delay = list(show = 800, hide = 100), trigger = "hover"),
      modal = TRUE # IMPORTANT!
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$openModal, {
    
    showModal(modalDialog(

      uiOutput("clip"),

      aceEditor(
        outputId = "aceEdId",
        value = "some code"
      )

    ))
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

